# Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Double'

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

1- Create an excel file like C:\MyFolder\Book1.xlsx.

2- Run following code and see that code is working good.

```
Option Strict Off
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    DateTimePicker1.Value = CDate(CStr(System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-System.DateTime.Now.Day)))

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    xlApp.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized

    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    wb1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyFolder\Book1.xlsx")

    Dim ws1 = CType(wb1.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

    With ws1
        .Range("A1").Value = "2017"
        If .Range("A1").Value.ToString <> CDbl(DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy")) Then
            MsgBox("error")
        End If
    End With

End Sub

End Class
```

5- I have errors when I turn Option Strict On.

Comment: Cells are going to be type Object since they can be a number, string, date etc.  Just cast it to the proper type before treating it as one type or another.  Usually, you want to check of it is Nothing/null/DBNull first to avoid other errors.

Comment: usually if you click on the blue squiggly, there will be a small red area you can click and get a suggested code fix from visual studio. It's not 100% always correct but a lot of times it is.

Comment: OK, have you tried not casting to dbl on the right side (ie, remove CDbl()?

Comment: `If .Range("A1").Value.ToString <> DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy") then` should not hilight that with the same error as both sides of the comparison are now the same type. Is it by chance throwing a different error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want compare string representation of `ws.Range("A1").Value` to the string representation of `DateTimePicker1.Value`.

Conversion of `DateTimePicker1.Value` to the `Double` seems odd. That is why compiler show error, because code

```
.Range("A1").Value.ToString <> CDbl(DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy"))
```

will try compare value of type `string` to value of type `double`, which is not allowed with `Strict Option On`.

Simply compare strings without converting to double

```
If .Range("A1").Value.ToString() <> DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy") Then
    MsgBox("error")
End If
```

Comment: An easier-to-read way might be `DateTimePicker1.Value.Year.ToString()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved.